# What is the parenthesis in the top-right corner of the Dwarf Fortress window?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

On the main screen of the game, in the very top-right corner of the screen (to the right of idlers and above current z-level), is a parenthesis that changes periodically between open and close parenthesis symbols. What does this signify?

Comment: Is it the moon phase indicator that was added in v0.34.01 per the release notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by Jason Aller is correct; it is the moon phase indicator. Apparently useful in relation to werebeasts.